# C# Sockets: Client not recieving all bytes when receiving large buffer

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client-server, buffer

So when the server sends less than **16384 bytes** then the client receives all the data with out a problem.
But once the server sends more than that then the client receives weird amounts, like 6140. It doesn't always do this, but it does most of the time, but it does it often. It very seldom receives the full 16384 bytes.

At first I thought the connection was just taking long to send the full amount, so I set the receive timeout to 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds).
That didn't solve anything. Each time I receive data I use a new byte array so that it doesn't get overwritten by another `BeginRecieve()`.

The only thing I can think of is that the hardware(Computer) cannot hold these large amounts of bytes in the memory, and therefore truncates the buffer.
I have a lot of code but this is the base of things:

Server code (Just some of it):

```
private void RecieveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    try
    {
        int len = client.EndReceive(ar);
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[len];
        Array.Copy(buffer, tempBuffer, len);
        object RequestObject = GetRequestObject(tempBuffer); // just deserializes the buffer
        byte[] response = GetResponseFromObject(RequestObject, client); // creates a buffer to return to the client
        client.BeginSend(response, 0, response.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), client);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Program.Log("Client disconnected");
        client.Close();
        clientSockets.Remove(client);
        Program.UpdateClientCount(clientSockets.Count);
    }
}

private void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    int sent = client.EndSend(ar);
    Program.Log(sent); // log shows that server sent 16384 bytes
    try
    {
        client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallBack), client);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Program.Log(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Client Code (Just some of it):

```
static void SendRequest(object obj)
{
    byte[] buffer = SerializeObject(obj);
    try
    {
        serverSockect.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), null);
    }
    catch // the send failed
    {
        serverSockect.Close();
        ConnectedToServer = false;
    }
}

static Queue<byte[]> buffers = new Queue<byte[]>();

static private void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    serverSockect.EndSend(ar);
    try
    {
        // Create a new buffer for each new BeginRecieve.
        // If one global buffer was used, then it might get overwritten by
        // a second request when the first request hasn't yet been completed.
        byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
        buffers.Enqueue(buffer);
        serverSockect.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(RecieveCallBack), null);
    }
    catch // the recieve failed
    {
        serverSockect.Close();
        ConnectedToServer = false;
    }
 }

static private void RecieveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    byte[] buffer = buffers.Dequeue();
    int len = serverSockect.EndReceive(ar); // len is usually some weird number
    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[len];
    Array.Copy(buffer, tempBuffer, len);
    object returnObj = GetResponseObject(tempBuffer);
    HandleResponse(returnObj);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're only getting the 1 packet and then moving on, not waiting for the rest

Comment: This sound like regular packet  fragmentation; have you checked whether the rest of the data arrives in the next  packet? It  isn't clear to me whether you try to continue reading after `ReceiveCallBack`. When using TCP, you should never rely on data arriving in the same pieces in which you sent it. All it offers is that the *stream* (when consumed) will get you all the right data in the right order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BugFinder already mentioned in the comments, TCP streams can be split into multiple packets. The packets will be received in the right order, but you can not be sure that the buffer contains the complete message. So in your receive method you have to combine the received data until you have a complete message.

On the other hand, short messages can be combined into one packet. Also the mixture of this two (packet 1 contains part 1 of message 1, packet 2 contains part 2 of message1 and part1 of message 2, packet 3 contains part 2 of message 2) is possible. Therefore you need a protocol that you can parse to recognize the end of a message.

If you have serialized objects, the best way would be to have at the beginning the length of the serialized object. But be sure to be able to handle the data right if not the complete data for the length was received. In the worst case, every byte could come in an own packet!

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I've been relying on a 1 send, 1 receive mind set. Do you perhaps have code or a link which has an example of how to handle multiple packets? I'm unsure of what method/properties to use to determine whether or not I need to wait for more packets. Thanks for the answer, I have looked into packets and sockets a bit more.

Comment: Please note I'm serializing objects and not just simple strings. So I can't simply add "<eof>" to the end of the string. This is the example I saw on the MSDN site for async server and client examples. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx - _server example_

Comment: updated the answer with a hint how to handle serialized objects.